# linux - c++ makefile not using include path

Tags: c++, linux, makefile

I'm having trouble running my makefile, it doesnt seem to use the include path i've specified.
The makefile looks like this:

```
SHELL   = /bin/sh
CC      = g++
FLAGS   = -std=c++0x
CFLAGS  = -Wall -fPIC -g -I/include
LDFLAGS = -shared

TARGET  = TNet.so
SOURCES = $(shell echo src/*.cpp)
HEADERS = $(shell echo include/*.h)
OBJECTS = $(SOURCES:.cpp=.o)


all: $(TARGET)

$(TARGET): $(OBJECTS)
    $(CC) $(FLAGS) $(CFLAGS) $(DEBUGFLAGS) -o $(TARGET) $(OBJECTS)

clean:
    -rm *.o $(TARGET
```

My directory tree looks like this:

```
  rootfolder
   /    \
src     include
```

any ideas?

Comment: `rootfolder` You really mean you placed your project under `/`?

Comment: no i just mean its the root folder for my project

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This `Makefile` works for me:

```
$ cat Makefile
CPPFLAGS = -Iinclude
CXXFLAGS = -Wall
foo: foo.cpp

$ make foo
g++ -Wall -I/include    foo.cpp   -o foo
```

It makes use of the already defined [implicit rules](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Implicit-Variables.html). In your case the flags to look for are:

```
CPPFLAGS
Extra flags to give to the C preprocessor and programs that use it (the C and Fortran compilers). 
CXXFLAGS
Extra flags to give to the C++ compiler.
```

Please note how the [-I dir](http://linux.die.net/man/1/cpp) is a flag for the pre processor, whereas the [-Wall](http://linux.die.net/man/1/g++) is usually a flag to the C++ compiler.

Comment: Thanks that worked! also follow up question: i get the compile error "undefined reference to 'main'". But i'm trying to compile a library, so shouldnt be any need for a main function? or am i missing something?

Comment: @Henningsson _"also follow up question ..."_ That's a completely different and unrelated question, ask another one please! Here's a hint though: [`What is an undefined reference/unresolved external symbol error and how do I fix it?`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix)

Answer (score 0):

Supposed your `Makefile` is actually placed under `rootfolder` and this is the working directory for your compiler call, you'll need to specify your include path not as an absolute path, but relative

```
CFLAGS  = -Wall -fPIC -g -I./include
```

or

```
CFLAGS  = -Wall -fPIC -g -Iinclude
```

Comment: still doesnt quite work, still get the same error message, also when i run make i get some strange output:
g++    -c -o src/client.o src/client.cpp
shouldnt there be more flags there? looks like all CFLAGS are excluded

Comment: @Henningsson Which error message exactly? Please edit your question to add this information. Also `SOURCES = $(shell echo src/*.cpp)` doesn't look correct for me, lookup `make functions` from the info.

Comment: @Henningsson Here's more info about [`make file name functions`](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#File-Name-Functions)

Answer (score 0):

Unless your project is directly under `/` you should add `-Include` to the compiler flags